# Use configuration file to specify connection string to define a data source in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am referring to this article for creating data-driven unit test cases using a connection string in `app.config` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-using-a-configuration-file-to-define-a-data-source?view=vs-2017

```
[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTest
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("MySQLDataSource")]
    public void TestRequestSummary()
    {
        string customerId = TestContext.DataRow["MessageId"].ToString();
        Assert.IsNotNull(customerId);
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" 
                 type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>    
        <add name="MySQL" 
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MYPortal;Integrated Security=True;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
        <dataSources>
            <add name="MySQLDataSource" connectionString="MySQL" 
                 dataTableName="ServiceLog" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
        </dataSources>
    </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
</configuration>
```

When I am trying to debug the test case it failed with the following error:

> Result2 StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.TestDataSource.GetData(ITestMethod testMethodInfo, ITestContext testContext)
>
> Result2 Message: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfiguration' threw an exception.

Could anyone help me solve this?

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2017
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
- .Net Framework 4.6

Comment: Are there any further details on on the stack trace with the error? One possible mismatch is the UnitTesting version, you have `Version=8.0.0.0` in the App.Config which may not be the same as the UnitTesting.dll you will have imported into the project

Comment: Even I thought the same and tried changing the version to `9.0/10.0/14.0` but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using MSTest v2 as my unit testing framework and it appears to be they have changed the configuration section for this particular version.

I found the answer in following thread:

https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/129#issuecomment-354124544

Code:

Changed my app.config file to:

```
<section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools"
         type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection,
         Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions"/>
```